# how to solve this Java Array default initialization

Tags: java

```
public class ApiClass{
 //The below method prints only the user entered values 
 public void printArray(int[] a){
   for(int element : a){
     //ignore because this is the default value when array is created not user entered
     if(element != 0)
     {
       System.out.print(element+"\t");
     }
   }
 }
}

public class Client{
  public static void main(String... args){
    ApiClass api = new ApiClass();
    int[] input = new int[5];
    input[0]= 3;
    input[2]= 2;
    input[3] = 1;
    api.printArray(input);
  }
}
```

This is working fine but failing for the 3,2,0 or 0,0,0 or 3,0,1 any input user enters with zero

Comment: Something to consider: I submit that your printArray method should not be the one deciding if a value is not fit to print. If the array contains the element, and the method is simply printing the array, then print it. If it needs to be filtered prior to printing, let some other entity have that responsibility.

Comment: can We achieve this in any other object oriented langauge?

Comment: @satya - What exactly is your question?? What do you want to achieve in any other OO-Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Satya:

If your problem is simply to distuingish the default 0-values from user-entered 0-values, why dont you initialize the array with a value that you know a user can never enter? (You need to make sure that this is the case).

One way is to iterate the array before and initialize, another one is to use
[Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

default value for primitive int type is 0 so the uninitilized elements in array will hold 0 value,

now if you check if element is not 0 then print and if you give input `3,2,0` then it will skip `0`

Better to use `List`

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(0);
numbers.add(3);
```

and now iterate the numbers

```
for(Integer num: numbers){
 //print num, no need to check for `0` any more
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good approach. If you have three user entries, you should make an array of length three (and not one of length five with two trailing un-used entries). There is no way to distinguish between the "default" 0 and a 0 assigned later.

Another option would be to use an `Integer[]`, where the "default" is null, not 0 (but then you cannot distinguish between the "default" null and a null assigned later).

If you don't know the length of the array in advance, use a `List<Integer>` instead.

Comment: why `Integer[]`, why not `List<Integer>` ?

Comment: _If you don't know the length of the array in advance, use a List<Integer> instead_ also another point we now don't need to check for default value any more if we use `List` we add only real value so no need to check for default values

Comment: @Thilo this is an interview question and interviewer does not agreed to use List<Integer>

Comment: @satya you should specify, Thilo +1

Comment: Can i achieve this in any other language?

Comment: Your interviewer is specific enough to not allow a Java List, but *other languages* are on the table?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, might be he want to prove this as shortcoming of java

Comment: There is no shortcoming here. If you want a variable-size array, you use an ArrayList.

Comment: can We achieve this in any other object oriented langauge?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong.

Should be

```
for(int element: a) {
 if(element !=0){
   System.out.println(element + "\t");
 }
}
```

Your initial implementation never incremented the value of i.

Comment: wait. You post flawed code and say it doesn't work. I tell you why, and you fix it. What was the question then?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
public void printArray(Integer[] a){
   for(Integer element : a){
    //Ignore because this is the default value when array is created not user entered
    if (element != null) {
      System.out.print(element.toString() + "\t");
    }
  }
}

public class Client{
  public static void main(String... args){
    ApiClass api = new ApiClass();
    Integer[] input = new Integer[5];
    input[0]= 3;
    input[2]= 2;
    input[3] = 1;
    api.printArray(input);
  }
}
```